# Spark - gzip decompression for binary files (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, gzip

Hi I am processing binary files with Spark on Java.
I know that text files (sc.textFile(path)) should be automatically decompressed if the extension of the file is ".gz".

Is there any similar automatic way to decompress binary data? Should I set some option I may need for it to work?
I tried this code and it seems that automatic decompression does not happen.

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
String inputFolder = args[0];
JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> binaryFiles = sc.binaryFiles(inputFolder);
```